# Polymer CLI not creating bower_components folder on Windows 7

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-cli

I installed node, bower and the polymer cli on a Windows 7 machine.

If I choose the "polymer-2-element" option and then defaults for the rest of the questions, the CLI builds a project but there is no bower_components folder created in the project.  There are no bower errors as it downloads files.  It is putting the files in the AppData\Local\bower\cache folder.

If I run the app with "polymer serve --open", the browser console shows 404's for anything in the bower_components folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a `bower.json`? if so what does it show?
did you try `bower install`

Comment: {
  "name": "polymerword",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^2.0.0-rc.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "iron-demo-helpers": "PolymerElements/iron-demo-helpers#2.0-preview",
    "web-component-tester": "v6.0.0-prerelease.5",
    "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#1.0.0-rc.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "polymer": "^2.0.0-rc.2”
  }
}

Comment: Running bower install still does not create a bower_components folder